# Rally custom grid with ((Parent = null) or (Parent.Name = 'xxxx'))

Tags: rally

Can you create a custom User Story grid in Rally with the following query?

(((Parent = null) AND (Owner.Name = "dummy.name@email.com")) OR ((Parent.Name contains "Example") AND (Owner.Name = "dummy.name@email.com")))

Every time I try to do this it only returns results for the second part of the query.  It seems like it cannot combine the Parent = null and the Parent.Name contains "Example".

Thanks for any feedback!  I know that we could create two grids, but it would be nice to combine it into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. Ignoring the owner portion of the query and taking just the Parent portions, per the title of your question: ((Parent = null) or (Parent.Name = 'xxxx')), it seems that I am also always seeing results that match the latter condition. If I switch the order, I get Parent-less stories. I'd recommend submitting a Case to Rally Support - rallysupport@rallydev.com - they can get this filed with the Rally developers.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I've opened a case with Rally Support.